# SQL SUM Help - Only returning 1 field

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL is only returning one field when it should be returning one for each user.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? If you need additional information I can provide, but I'm just not sure where to go with this at the moment.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT uId, uForename, SUM(biProductPrice * biQuantity) AS uTotalSpent 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN orders ON uId = ordUserId 
LEFT JOIN basket ON ordUserId = bUserId 
LEFT JOIN basketitems ON bId = biBasketId 
WHERE ordStatus BETWEEN 4 AND 50
GROUP BY uId, uForename
```

any columns starting with u belong to the users table.

any columns starting with ord belong to the orders table.

any columns starting with b belong to the basket table.

any columns starting with bi belong to the basketitems table.

EDIT:

Everything now works fine except for my SUM, there are only 2 fields with an ordStatus between 4 and 50, so they are the only ones that apply, the biQuantity for one is 8 and the biProductPrice is 100, the other field has a biQuantity of 1 and a biProductPrice of 100, why is it returning a value of 400?

Comment: You didn't specify any `GROUP BY` clause there ...

Comment: I am not a fan of this naming convention. Yuk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, SUM(biProductPrice) AS uTotalSpent 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN orders ON uId = ordUserId 
LEFT JOIN basket ON ordUserId = bUserId 
LEFT JOIN basketitems ON bId = biBasketId 
WHERE ordStatus BETWEEN 4 AND 50
group by users.uId, users.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by the user and the sum will be returned for each one

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, SUM(biProductPrice) AS uTotalSpent 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN orders ON uId = ordUserId 
LEFT JOIN basket ON ordUserId = bUserId 
LEFT JOIN basketitems ON bId = biBasketId 
WHERE ordStatus BETWEEN 4 AND 50
group by users.uId, users.name
```

Comment: Assuming the user id is unique, no need to add the user name.

Comment: @AzizSaleh: If you want to select the users name then you have to add it to the group by clause.

Comment: This does work yes, but now I have a new issue, see edit above in 1 mo ^

Comment: @MarkOverton: You do a `left join` and include many rows. That is why yours sum is too high. If you add example data it would be easier to help. Can you [build a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: @juergend If the mapping between the user id and username is one-to-one (which is generally) then a group by Id is sufficient, it would still select the username as well as any other fields in the SELECT statement.